# How do I fix "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" for my formulas?

Tags: python

I am trying to input equations into python and can't get it right...

Here is my code:

```
def standpipe_ar(k, H, ps, Eg, Ds, fw, L, Us):
    import sqr
    return (k / H) * [((sqr.sqr(ps) * (1 - Eg) * 9.81 * Ds) / (4 * fw)) * ((22 / 7) * Ds * L)] * Us

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("TEST: Standpipe Att. Rate =",
          standpipe_ar(0.01, 800000000.0, 4600.0, 0.4, 0.05, 0.2, 1.0, 0.3))
```

The `sqr` function works as I have tested it already (all it does is square a number).

Whenever I try to run this file to test it, the error I keep getting is:

> `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Can anyone please help???

Comment: Don't use a list: you have square brackets, resulting in a 1-element list, which is unnecessary. Perhaps you want parentheses instead?

Comment: Okay thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As k and H are floats, (k/H) turns out to be a float. You cant multiply a sequence with a float, must be an int. Also multiplying a sequence will expand the sequence which I am guessing isn't what you want. I believe what you are probably looking is a result. You can simply get rid of the [ ] brackets.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get that.  Look at your return expression:

```
return (k / H) *                             # This is a float
       [ ((sqr.sqr(ps) * more_terms ) ] *      # This is a list
       Us                                    # This is a float
```

You cannot replicate a list  times.  Did you intend this to be a simple multiplication of float values?  If so, then get rid of the brackets: those indicate a list or comparable structure -- they're not the same as parentheses.

Comment: Thank you! that makes a lot of sense! I really appreciate it!